# The page you tried to access (/manager/projects) does not exist - intellij 13.1 under tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, http-status-code-404

I want to run web project on intellij 13.1 under tomcat 7.0.52.

This application has 3 roles - admin / manager / user.

And when I want to access manager role it shows - **404 Not found**:

[image: manager]

here is snippet of **LoginServlet**

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = MD5Utils.getMD5String(request.getParameter("password"));
    User user = null;
    try {
        user = new UserService().getByEmail(email);
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }

    if (user != null) {
        if (!ValidationUtils.isNullOrEmpty(user.getEmail()) && user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            log.info("Logged in: " + user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
            if (session.getAttribute("waitUrl") != null) {
                String url = session.getAttribute("waitUrl").toString();
                response.sendRedirect(url);
            } else {
                String contextPath = request.getContextPath();

                if (user.getRoleId().equals(1)) { // 1=user role
                    response.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/user/tasks");
                } if (user.getRoleId().equals(2)) { // 2 manager role
                    response.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/manager/projects");
                } if (user.getRoleId().equals(3)) { // 3 admin role
                    response.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/admin/users");
                }

            }
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("loginErrors", "Wrong email or password");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

From Login it's renderer to:

```
@WebServlet("/manager/projects")
public class OutProjects extends HttpServlet {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(OutProjects.class);
    private ProjectService projectService;
    private List<Project> projects;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        projectService = new ProjectService();
        updateTable();
    }

    private void updateTable() {
        try {
            projects = projectService.getListOfObjects();
        } catch (DAOException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("projects", projects);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/manager/projects.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

and next **jsp**:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<c:set var="language"
       value="${not empty param.language ? param.language : not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}"
       scope="session"/>
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.java.task11.i18n.text"/>

<html lang="${language}">
<head>
    <title>Projects</title>
    <jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="tableContainer-1">
        <TABLE class="table table-bordered" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th><fmt:message key="project.name"/></th>
                <th><fmt:message key="project.description"/></th>
                <th><fmt:message key="project.notes"/></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="project" items="${sessionScope.projects}">
                <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pages/manager/updateprojects" name="updateProject" method="post">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${project.id}</td>
                        <td>${project.projectName}</td>
                        <td>${project.description}</td>
                        <td>${project.notes}</td>

                        <td><button class="btn btn-inverse" type="submit" name="update" value="${project.id}">
                            <fmt:message key="button.update"/></button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="delete" value="${project.id}">
                            <fmt:message key="button.delete"/></button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="project_id" value="${project.id}">
                            <fmt:message key="project.tasks"/></button></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </c:forEach>

            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pages/manager/addproject.jsp"> <fmt:message key="button.addProject"/></a>
            </tbody>
        </TABLE>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I couldn't figure out why this happen?

I looked into `tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<role rolename="admin" />
<role rolename="tomcat" />
<role rolename="developer" />
<role rolename="customer" />
<role rolename="user" />

<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,tomcat,user,customer" />
<user username="nazar" password="nazar" roles="admin,tomcat,developer,customer,user" />
<user username="developer" password="developer" roles="admin,tomcat,developer,customer,user" />
```

***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Tomcat's Manager application deployed at the context path /manager so any request that starts with /manager is routed to that application. It looks like you need to undeploy Tomcat's manager application to allow your application to handle URLs starting with /manager.